# How to indicate that verification/correction is requested in the document

Tags: writing, tech-writing, writing-advice

I’ve been tasked to write a document (like a wiki) about an application for work. I don't know much about the app, other than what I'm understanding by reading the source code and minimal business requirements. As such, there are some assumptions I'm making in the document that I want verified/clarified by anyone reading it who knows more about that particular feature. Is there some kind of "grammatical feedback" *(kind of like when people use **(sp?)** to indicate that they are unsure of a word spelling)* that I could use to annotate a particular phrase or word?

For instance:

> This controller provides *[access to the following CRUD
>   operations ]* (unsure of bracketed text)

Thanks.

Comment: There isn't and I suggest if what you describe is being asked of more than two or three of your people, your organisation would be better off putting all those reports on hold until someone - which might be you - has written a set of procedures for handling such reports, including and by no means limited to what you ask…

Comment: If using modern text editing or word processing software, you can mark a section of the text and add a comment, even if it's your own document.

Answer (score 1):

As your question implies, I would use "(verify)" or "(confirm)" in parentheses, or any suitable abbreviation i.e. (ver?), (conf?).